# Generate all subsets of {0,1}^N with exactly N/2 zeroes/ones

Tags: r

I'm trying to generate with R all the sequences of length N (suppose N is even), such that the number of zeroes is exactly N/2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is what you're looking for. I used `expand.grid` to generate all possible binary combinations and selected those of it that had `N/2` ones in it.

```
bin.combs <- function(N){
  cbs <- as.matrix(expand.grid(rep(list(0:1),N)))
  cbs <- cbs[rowSums(cbs)==N/2,]
  unname(cbs)
}

# > bin.combs(4)
#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
# [1,]    1    1    0    0
# [2,]    1    0    1    0
# [3,]    0    1    1    0
# [4,]    1    0    0    1
# [5,]    0    1    0    1
# [6,]    0    0    1    1
```

**EDIT:**

```
# @Matthew Lundberg
bin.combs3 <- function(N){
  apply(combn(N,N/2), 2, FUN=function(x) 1:N %in% x)
}

# @Bernardo
bin.combs2 <- function(N){
  vec <- rep(c(0,1),N/2)
  cbs <- permn(vec)
  cbs[!duplicated(cbs)]
}
```

Here's a benchmark for the solutions proposed so far. Results indicate that mine and @Matthews solution are pretty close.

```
microbenchmark(bin.combs(8), bin.combs2(8), bin.combs3(8), times=20)
# Unit: microseconds
#             expr        min         lq        mean      median          uq        max neval
#     bin.combs(8)    551.916    586.021    788.5850    663.6950    736.8880   3200.565    20
#    bin.combs2(8) 483857.505 522567.683 546706.0648 545832.1185 561677.2175 672247.779    20
#    bin.combs3(8)    688.192    749.524    809.2446    795.3495    874.2095   1003.857    20
```

Answer (score 2):

`combn` gets combinations.  Then you can select those entries from 1:N.  The columns in the matrix below are the solution.

```
> f <- function(N) apply(combn(N,N/2), 2, FUN=function(x) 1:N %in% x)
> f(4)
      [,1]  [,2]  [,3]  [,4]  [,5]  [,6]
[1,]  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE
[2,]  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
[3,] FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE
[4,] FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE
```

Answer (score 1):

An alternative to SimonG's approach is to firstly define a vector with number of zeroes and ones you want and then get all permutations with the package `combinat`. Should be more eficient, specially for large N, since you don't have to generate all possibilities and then subset it.

```
library(combinat)
N = 4
vec = rep(c(0,1),N/2)
permn(vec)
```

Comment: It doesn't give the same solution though, because it produces duplicate combinations. If I fix that using `cbs <- permn(vec); cbs[!duplicated(cbs)]`, my solution is actually faster (and increasingly so for larger `Ǹ`). Is there a better way to fix it? Then I would prepare a benchmark.

Comment: @SimonG, thanks! I'll look into that, didn't see it was producing duplicate combinations. If I can improve it, I'll edit it later